# Printing 2d array with top and left indexes

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I would like to create 2D array which looks like this:

```
  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
A ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~
B ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~
C ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~
D ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~
E ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~
F ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~
G ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~
H ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~
I ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~
J ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~
```

I tried doing it like this:

```
public char[][] fillFieldWithWarFog() {
    char[] indices = " ABCDEFGHIJ".toCharArray();
    for (int row = 0; row < gameField.length; row++) {
        for (int i = 0; i < indices.length; i++) {
            gameField[row][0] = indices[i];
        }
        for (int col = 1; col < gameField[row].length; col++) {
            gameField[row][col] = '~';
        }
    }
    return this.gameField;
}
```

But instead of ABCD and so on values in first array column I have only 'J' values.

```
  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
J ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ 
J ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ 
J ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ 
J ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ 
J ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ 
J ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ 
J ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ 
J ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ 
J ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ 
J ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ 
J ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~
```

Could you give me a hint how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It wasn't clear if you wanted the column numbers as part of your array.  But to print the array with the indices, you can do it like this.

```
public char[][] fillFieldWithWarFog() {
    char[] indices = "ABCDEFGHIJ".toCharArray();
    for (int row = 0; row < gameField.length; row++) {
            gameField[row][0] = indices[row];
        for (int col = 1; col < gameField[row].length; col++) {
            gameField[row][col] = '~';
        }
    }
    return this.gameField;
}

char[][] fog = fillFieldWithWarFog();


for (int row = 0; row < fog.length; row++) {
    for (int col = 0; col < fog[row].length; col++) {
        System.out.printf(" %s", fog[row][col]);
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Prints

```
 A ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~
 B ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~
 C ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~
 D ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~
 E ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~
 F ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~
 G ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~
 H ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~
 I ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~
 J ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~
```

Answer (score 1):

Preparing an array for printing - adding top and left indices:

```java
private static String printArray(char[][] arr, int d) {
    // line with digits above the field
    String title = "  " + IntStream.range(1, d)
            .mapToObj(i -> (char) ('0' + i))
            .map(String::valueOf)
            .collect(Collectors.joining(" ")) + " " + d;

    // add letters to the left of each row of the field
    String field = IntStream.range(0, d)
            .mapToObj(i -> (char) ('A' + i) +
                    String.valueOf(arr[i]).replace("", " "))
            .collect(Collectors.joining("\n"));

    return title + "\n" + field;
}
```

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int d = 10;
    char[][] field = new char[d][d];
    Arrays.stream(field).forEach(arr -> Arrays.fill(arr, '~'));

    System.out.println(printArray(field, d));
}
```

Output:

```
  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
A ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ 
B ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ 
C ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ 
D ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ 
E ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ 
F ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ 
G ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ 
H ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ 
I ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ 
J ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~
```